# two or more data types in declaration of ‘t’

Tags: c++, data-structures, inline

**I am trying to write my own coding template for programming.
So basically I am trying to write inline or preprocessor for fetching number of test cases in coding problem.**

So generally I do like this-

```
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
//code
}
```

## I tried two things here

```
#define test int t; cin>>t; while(t--)
inline void test(){int t; cin>>t; while(t--)}
```

> for the first case, error is - two or more data types in declaration
>   of ‘t’. And for the second case, error is - error: expected
>   primary-expression before ‘}’ token

What am I doing wrong? Please suggest.
P.S I am new to c++ language

Comment: Ugh, "competitive" programming strikes again... For good readability, you should do neither of those things. In function, `while` is missing a body. You cannot just leave it hanging like that. For macro, the error comes probably from where you use it, rather than macro definition.

Comment: The problem is that you expect a macro and a function definition to behave the same way, and they don't.   The preprocessor does TEXT substitution, and produces source code as output, which is then compiled.   You have a macro `test` and the preprocessor does text substitution into the next line, which then looks like `inline void int t; cin >> t while(t--) {int t; cin >> t; while (t--)}`.

Comment: Generally macros are not a good approach, it should be used carefully in specific cases. So the inlined function would be a better solution. It seems like you miss a ‘;’ after the while statement :(

Comment: The second case is an incorrect C++ program.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk - the "`define`" is not being called (macros don't get called anyway).   Text substitution is performed on the following line, and produces rubbish code (as per my previous comment) that triggers the compiler diagnostic.

Comment: @Peter you're right. I was trying to phrase it so the question will be clear to the op.

Comment: This is a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I've got feeling that you overthink some simple problem and you have come up with this strange solution. Now you are asking to fix your solution instead asking how to solve actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code could be put into a function:

```
 void func(int i)
 {.../*code*/... }
```

And then the template function takes this function, so it will look like:

```
 void template_func(void (*f)(int) )
 {
     int t;
     cin>>t;
     while(t--)
         f(t) ;
  }
```

This will be called :

```
template_func(func) ;
```

---

Another way is with `template`'s

```
template<typename Callable>
void template_func(Callable f )
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
        f(t) ;
 }
```

To call that :

```
template_func(func);
```

---

With C++17 inside `template_func`, `std::is_invocable` can be used to verify that the function passed is invokable:

```
static_assert( std::is_invocable_v< decltype(f), int>) ;
```

Comment: I'd rather see a template (to accept any callable and not just callables, that can decay to pointer)

Comment: Your call is wrong. It should be `template_func(func);`.